# In ruby, what does this regex do? /((\w)\2*)/

Tags: ruby, regex

```
"aaabbcde".scan(/((\w)\2*)/)
```

This line of code will get a result as below

```
[["aaa", "a"], ["bb", "b"], ["c", "c"], ["d", "d"], ["e", "e"]]
```

The part where I don't understand is what `\2*` does. And why does this generate a two dimension array?

Edited:

Just a summary from what I understand after getting helps and doing some research. Hope this would help anyone searching for similar topic.

You can create capture groups using regex. And the latter group can refer to earlier group.
Each parentheses is a capture group. So if you do this `/(\w)/`, you create 1 group, and it will extract all the word characters, and put each single character into an individual group.

So you will get something like this with a string `"rubyy"`

```
Match 1
1.  r
Match 2
1.  u
Match 3
1.  b
Match 4
1.  y
Match 5
1.  y
```

To create a second capture group, you just need to add another pair of parentheses, like this `/((\w))/`. But note that, the outer pair of parentheses is the first group, and the inner one is the second group. And this can go forth and forth and forth.

Given the same string `"rubyy"`, this would have a result like this.

```
Match 1
1.  r
2.  r
Match 2
1.  u
2.  u
Match 3
1.  b
2.  b
Match 4
1.  y
2.  y
Match 5
1.  y
2.  y
```

You can try to change the regex to `/(()\w)/`, or `/(\w)()/` and see what happen (remember I just said the inner pair of parentheses is the second group?). http://www.rubular.com is a good place to experiment your regex in ruby.

A pointer that refers to another capture group:
So the regex I originally asked about, `/((\w)\2*)/`, `\2` this part just means "give me what you get from group #2 (the inner one is group #2), and put it in group #1 (the outer one, where `\2` is). Then `*` is just a regular regex that means zero or more. In this case, zero or more of what group #2 extracted.

Give the above understanding, you can try do this `/(\w)(\1*)/`. This would achieve something similar too. But you should experiment the difference. And remember, `/(\2*)(\w)/` don't work, because I guess ruby runs sequantially in this type of parallel structure, so `\2` points to a capture group that didn't exist yet.

Comment: Its regex; `\2` is placeholder for internal referrer (the second set of parentheses) `*` matches 0 or more repetitions.

Comment: I have found http://rubular.com/ very useful for testing and developing regexes.

Comment: I am using that too. But thanks, @BSeven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two capture groups, the first one, `((\w)\2*)`, being the first encountered when parsed left-to-right, the second being `(\w)`. `\2*` matches the result of capture group #2, zero or more times.

For `"aaa"`, the inner capture group (#2) matches the first `"a"`, then `\2*` becomes `a*`, which matches the next two `a`'s. Hence, the first capture group matches `'aaa'`.

Notice that capture group #2 always matches just one character.

Comment: So each pair of parentheses is a capture group. I get it. Then `\w` extracts all the word character. The parentheses put all of them into a group (which is group #2?). Then `\2` find the result that matches group #2. `*` Take zero of more of the result that did the match. Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: Yes, assuming you mean `\w` extracts one word character.

Comment: Why can't the second capture group be ignored? So that only the repeated matches will be shown.

Comment: @JikkuJose, the second capture group, `(\w)` is needed so there can be a back-reference to the first character of the string of identical characters. A second capture group (the outer one) is then needed to capture that string of identical characters. It may seem logical that the inner capture group should be #1, but that's not the way it works. Does that answer your question?

Comment: No sorry, my question is quite different; will post as a question; it may help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following

- anything inside the `//` is a regular expression pattern to match
- `\2` is a variable (called a backreference) to point to whatever is matched in the second set of parentheses, in this case the `\w`.  If it was matched in another parentheses, you'd use `\3`; these unescaped parentheses are known as capture groups
- `*` is a 0 or more match

For a better explanation, refer to any of the plethora of guides about regex.  For example: http://www.regular-expressions.info/refcapture.html

Comment: So the inner pair of parentheses is the second set that you refer to?

Comment: @EdmundLee No, I think it works from the inside out.  However, backreferences can be used in the group they are referencing.

Comment: I am thinking it might work outside in. Because if I do this `(()\w)`, the matches are put in the second group. I tried it in this ruby regex editor [link](http://rubular.com/) @vol7ron

Comment: Wait, yes, I think I missed that up.  You're right; the internal group is the `\2`

Comment: Got it. Thanks. OK, this might sound stupid. But would you recommend doing it in a parallel structure? I could achieve sort of the same result by this `(\w)(\1*)`. It just puts the matches I need into the second group instead.

Comment: That would depend on what you're trying to accomplish, but that looks more clear. Regex can be highly inefficient and there are all kinds of tips and tricks to optimize it, which I don't remember but tend to refer to books that list them out. I'd suggest the same.